# Measurement error in maximum counts

Tags: error, extreme-value

I'm familiar with the concept of a mean value of data and the variation around the mean. Is it possible to quantify variation around maximum values?

For example, take the below data collected across 10 years. I want to present the maximum value for each month, but I also want to quantify the variation around the maximum value for each month across the 10 years:

```
counts <- data.frame(year = sort(rep(2000:2009, 12)), month = rep(month.abb,10), count = sample(1:500, 120, replace = T))
```

First 20 rows of data:

```
head(counts, 20)

   year month count
1  2000   Jan    14
2  2000   Feb   182
3  2000   Mar   462
4  2000   Apr   395
5  2000   May   107
6  2000   Jun   127
7  2000   Jul   371
8  2000   Aug   158
9  2000   Sep   147
10 2000   Oct    41
11 2000   Nov   141
12 2000   Dec    27
13 2001   Jan    72
14 2001   Feb     7
15 2001   Mar    40
16 2001   Apr   351
17 2001   May   342
18 2001   Jun    81
19 2001   Jul   442
20 2001   Aug   389
```

What quantities can I use: Standard deviation? Interquartile range? Range of maximum values? Confidence intervals?

Comment: You can certainly calculate sd, interquartile range and range. CI are trickier. What will you do with the information?

Comment: Take a look at [Extreme Value Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory), and [distribution of sample min and max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_maximum_and_minimum).

Answer (score -1):

It will be hard to even define what you mean by "measurement error of maximum counts".

In case of mean it is easy, because mean is a parameter of underlying theoretical distribution that generated your data. This parameter can be estimated along with its uncertainty.

Maximum, on the other hand, is *not* a parameter of the distribution - the distribution has no maximum! So when you speak about maximum, it is always maximum of your *sample*.

This puts Bayesian statistics off because it considers your data as fixed. You will have to use either some direct frequentist approach, which considers model as fixed and your data being actually sample of your model. The inference could be either direct or by using [**bootstrapping**](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html). I am not very strong in deriving complex frequentist maximum likelihood formulas, so I will just give you a bootstrapping example on your data:

```
library(boot)

counts <- data.frame(year = sort(rep(2000:2009, 12)), month = rep(month.abb,10), count = sample(1:500, 120, replace = T))

# this is how you compute the maximum
aggregate(counts$count, list(counts$month), max)

# function which does it for a sub-sample given by `indices`
month_max <- function (data, indices) {
    d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
    return (tapply(d$count, d$month, max))
}

# bootstrapping with 1000 replications
results <- boot(data=counts, statistic=month_max, R=1000)
results
# ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
# [...]
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#      original  bias    std. error
# t1*       466 -28.364    48.41140
# t2*       496 -27.725    40.78849
# t3*       455 -40.789    57.09997
# t4*       499 -32.997    47.74439
# t5*       466 -15.057    34.23477
# t6*       484 -15.966    39.79838
# t7*       491 -24.337    38.84459
# t8*       370 -24.701    39.31971
# t9*       474 -28.850    57.94352
# t10*      448 -23.793    59.52596
# t11*      446 -64.173    84.13633
# t12*      398 -22.229    36.31511
```

You see the results correspond to the real values, but also include a standard error. You can see the bias is quite high. This indicates that the "real" max value lies out of the sampled ones, which is normal for `max` function and will not happen for `mean`.

You can report the CI too (perhaps there is a better way, but this works):

```
for (i in 1:12) {
    print(boot.ci(results, type="bca", index=i))
}
```

Comment: Not all distributions have means, e.g. Breit-Wigner. I also would not characterize mean as a parameter of distribution. Some r.v.s have maximums.

Comment: Trying to frame this as a question of inference is problematic, as you note.  But the situation is simple.  The maximum of a sample is a statistic.  It will have a sampling distribution.  Estimating that sampling distribution can be done in standard ways in any of the major statistical paradigms, both Frequentist and Bayesian.  Parametric approaches are practically needed, but with sufficiently large amounts of data non-parametric approaches (based on extreme value theory) can be applied, too.

Comment: Bootstrapping is not usually a good idea with maximum (or minimum.)